# Upvote increases rating with +2

Tags: discussion, down-votes, up-votes, daily-reputation-limit

Mates,

I'm wondering why was my rating increased by `+2` after I had received a downvote. Or it's something that is supposed to happen (by rules) when a downvote is received ?

[image]

Comment: Congrats, you hit the rep cap.

Comment: What does this mean ? No matter how much reputation I receive it will just stay the same until tomorrow ?

Comment: @kocko 200 rep is the max from upvotes per day. You can still earn more from accepted answers and bounty rewards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To explain, let's give number to each upvote:

> [image]

After #1 you had 190 daily reputation from votes only. After #2, you had 200. That's the limit. However, the downvote caused it to be 198, hence upvote #3 gave the maximum it could until the daily limit was hit again, which is only 2. Without that downvote, you would have seen just an empty space instead of reputation gain.

Comment: Thank you. Now it's clear to me.

Answer (score 5):

There is a daily limit of +200 reputation that can be earned from upvotes.  Earning from anything else (accepted answers, bounties, etc) still add to your reputation.  Downvotes go against that cap, so if you get downvoted, then subsequently upvoted, you'll get back that lost reputation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :)